# Why Cant Get Linear Regression Line on Logarithmic Scale

Tags: c#, linear-regression, syncfusion, math.net

I’ve tried to Math.NET C# Fit.Line function with the aim of finding the linear regression model based on some data. The result is proper with the regression method but not seeming as a stright on logarithmic scale. I’m working on logarithmic scale and my question is that how can I get the straight model on a logarithmic scale?

My example is here:

```
double[] xdata = new double[] { 10, 20, 30 };
double[] ydata = new double[] { 15, 20, 25 };

Tuple<double, double> p = Fit.Line(xdata, ydata);
double a = p.Item1;
double b = p.Item2;
```

If the values will be displayed on a logarithmic scale, there could not be get any linear straight line, it seems to curve more. and I would like to show linear regression ax+b as a straight

Comment: Your question is unclear; is your log scale semi-log or log-log?

Comment: @EricLippert My scale is semi-log, based on X-axis. After the least-squares calculation, I found the linear regression coefficient a and b, then created a ax+b line. But, the problem, ax+b linear regression line could not be shown as a straight line on x-axis semi-log scale; it's like a curve.

Comment: That's correct. A straight line on a semi-log scale represents a function like 2-to-the-x, not a function like `ax + b`.  The only function of that form that is a straight line on a semi log scale is if `a` is zero. If you want a linear function to be a straight line, don't use a semi-log scale. Use a normal scale or a log-log scale.

Comment: Note that on a log-log scale, a polynomial will be a straight line, and on a semi-log scale, an exponential will be a straight line.

Comment: @EricLippert Because of my scientific research, I have to use a semi-logarithmic scale. If you take that into consideration, what kind of solution would you propose?

Comment: Its science. I propose that you accurately report your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a visual illustration of the comment from @EricLippert showing the exact same "y = ax + b" straight line plotted in different ways. First, standard linear scaling, where the regression line appears straight:

[image: standard_scaling]:

Now the exact same plot, but with with Y axis as log scaling:

[image: log_y]

And here with log X scaling:

[image: log_x]

And finally with both axes log scaled:

[image: log_log]